# Where is $f(z)=\frac{2z+1}{z(z^2+1)}$ analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

I have to find the points where $f(z)=\dfrac{2z+1}{z(z^2+1)}$ is analytic.

My idea is, denoting $z=x+\mathrm iy$, we find the functions $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ first by multiplying the conjugate of the denominator:
$$\frac{2z+1}{z(z^2+1)}\cdot\frac{\overline{z^3+z}}{\overline{z^3+z}},$$
then using the Cauchy-Riemann equations to find the points. But, just finding $u(\cdot,\cdot)$ and $v(\cdot,\cdot)$ is an arduous task due to the resulting expansion.

Is this correct, or is there a simpler method (preferably similar) to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f'(z)=\dfrac{z(z^2+1)(2)-(2z+1)[(z^2+1)+2z^2]}{z^2(z^2+1)^2}$ exists precisely at the points where the denominator is not zero, namely $z\ne 0,i,-i$.  Thus that's where $f(z)$ is analytic.

Answer (score 0):

$f(z)$ is not analytic at its poles.

By looking at the denominator, you can see that it has poles at $z=0,i,$ and $-i$.

Comment: analytic, in a sense, means complex differentiable. where there are non-removable singularities like poles or essential singularities, the function fails to be analytic